# Importing code into Eclipse when it's not a project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

I'm scratching my head here, trying to figure out how to get an already existing library into Eclipse.

With AndEngine it was easy, as i could simply import it as a project. However, with this one, I cannot do that (the importer doesn't find any projects in the source tree). How would I import code not archived as a project?

The specific import in question is: https://github.com/sm4/AndEngine/tree/GLES2-AnchorCenter

If it matters, I need to reference it from this Android project

Comment: Check whether you have another project in your workspace with the same name. The project link you have added is a perfect one.

Comment: @intrepidkarthi I never doubted the code that i linked, but my method of importing it was obviously flawed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can download their src and then drag and drop their package into your src folder... Thats one way atleast.. If you want to leave it in Jar form, you can drop the Jar into your source folder, add it to build path, and then use it in your project.

Comment: I would add jar files to the /lib directory

Comment: I was thinking of just dropping the src tree into my project, but unsure if that would open a can of worms with crossreferences and whatnot. Also, It would require me to do the same with any other projects using the library. Butbut, if there's no easier way, i'll just have to.

Comment: You can do like jaytj95 said and put the JAR into a lib folder, just make sure to add it to build path